# Would it be feasible to have a compiler directly/manually emit LLVM IR?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

Would manually emitting LLVM IR instead of using the LLVM API/bindings be feasible? Few languages have LLVM bindings and often they are outdated or lack good documentation, I would really like to avoid C++, so emitting LLVM IR directly would allow me to use my language of choice (F#).

Just to be clear, I am looking to write my own little compiler that targets LLVM, so I can use the LLVM ARM backend to generate code for ARM Cortex M microcontrollers.

Comment: What do you mean by feasible? The LLVM language specification defines the IR in its entirety, including the textual representation. As far as I know it has been stable for many years. Compilers have been emitting assembly code for decades. Why would this be fundamentally different? As for whether it's *preferable* to using a potentially buggy binding I think comes down to personal opinion.

Comment: Well is manually emitting LLVM IR a lot more work than using the API? I mean obviously everything is possible, but the question is whether it is a good idea. Please keep in mind that I have never written a compiler before and am completely new to LLVM.

Comment: Apologies if I came across as harsh - that was not my intent! :-) I think this is one of those times where it's best to just *try it*. I don't see any reason why emitting LLVM IR in its textual form would be significantly more difficult than emitting, say, x86-64 assembly code. If you find the quality of the F# LLVM bindings lacking (or if there simply aren't any), you may very well be better off generating the textual representation.

Comment: Use C bindings instead, they're quite comprehensive now. No need to go via C++. It's trivial to generate p/invoke .net wrappers around llvm-c, see an example here: https://github.com/combinatorylogic/clike/tree/master/llvm-wrapper (python cindex is used to parse llvm-c headers)

Comment: Doesn't this question reduce to "Is LLVM IR code stable", e.g. cross version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some definition of feasible, yes. The Glasgow Haskell Compiler [emits LLVM bitcode](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/Backends/LLVM/Design) ([see also](http://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/#haskell-llvm-bindings) -- the whole tutorial at that link may be of interest actually)

Before going down that road, you may wish to consider some existing solutions:

- http://www.llvmsharp.org/
- https://github.com/fsprojects/llvm-fs

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to f# I'd recommend making a c++/CLI assembly for the parts you need.  Writing out text and reparsing it is slower, depending on the size of your use case and generating the correct text and checking identifier names has its own class of issues.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what you mean ;) Could you clarify your answer a bit? I am neither .Net expert nor an expert in VMs and compilers, I've only recently become interested in the field and the only thing that I have so far done that is remotely related is writing a tiny stack machine.Just to be clear I meant writing the compiler that emits LLVM IR in F#.

Comment: Sure, c++/CLI is a project type in visual studio where you can create .NET assemblies, usable by any .NET language including F#, which can make normal c++ calls.  This would allow you to write a wrapper for accessing LLVM from within F#.

As someone pointed out though, it looks like the LLVMSharp project has already done the legwork so I'd use their library if possible to save a lot of boilerplate work.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, for the clarification. This explains why I didn't understand your comment, I have never used VS (I use Mac OS X and formerly used Linux). I will take a look at the LLVMSharp project. I should say that I have decided to postpone the whole LLVM compiler stuff though, as I feel I am not knowledgeable enough yet (I should note that I am currently still in high school, so I haven't even been able to attend a language/compiler class yet ;) ). Although I will always remain interested in the VM/compiler field, so I will probably come back later in the not too distant future ;)